# Rebuild form in AJAX callback

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I've got a simple form which I've added a little AJAX to. The form simply let's people add users to a list. That is, I've got a textfield where people can enter an e-mail address, and that e-mail address gets added to the list.

Now, the "Add" button is AJAX enabled, meaning that the add request gets posted as an AJAX request. However, I would then like the AJAX callback function to render the form again so that the newly added user appears in the list. However, I can't really see how I should do this.

I've tried to build the form ("from scratch") using drupal_get_form() in the AJAX callback function and then return that form, but that does not work. It just gives me the error :

```
Notice: Undefined index: form_build_id in /home/playground/www/public_html/includes/ajax.inc on line 320
```

How should I go about when I would like to rebuild the form from the very scratch as a part of the AJAX request, and then return that form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AJAX callback, use `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` ([drupal_rebuild_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_rebuild_form/7)).

$form_state['rebuild'] is very useful in multistep forms, but it can also be handy in Ajax callbacks.

I recommend checking out the [Examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) project as well.  Both the Form examples and the AJAX examples.

If you will add the relevant snippets of your code I will try to add more details.

Comment: Thank's for that! I have built multistep forms before, and I've often used the $form_state['rebuild'], but I what I did not remember was that i needed to set it in the submit callback and not in the ajax callback :-)

Thanks for pointing me onto the right track!

Comment: I realize this answer is quite old, but I wonder: How is setting $form_state['rebuild'] in an AJAX callback supposed to have any effect? If you look at [ajax_form_callback](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/function/ajax_form_callback/7) you can clearly see that the form has already been processed once the callback gets invoked.

Comment: Downvote because @ciss is right - the ajax callback is called to late to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to do it old way.

In D7 your form building code runs on initial form display and on subsequent ajax calls. You can make use of `$form_state` parameter there to render the form according to freshly entered data.

You attach a '#callback' attribute to ajaxified elements. Most examples show returning one particular element in a callback. But it's just a convenient special case. There is a powerful Ajax Commands API, it can be used to request execution of a wide range of operations on a client from a server.

No need to manually rebuilding forms or something like that. Just look at the examples on http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7.